# Marici (Mareechi), in Jainism and Hinduism. Are they the same?

Tags: other-religions, rishi, jainism

Hinduism has Rishi Marici, who is one of the Saptarshis. Wikipedia says that he is the founder of Vedanta. However the first systematized book on Vedanta is the Brahma Sutras, composed by Badarayana. And the pre-Brahma-Sutra Vedantic authors which we find are Ashmarathya, Badari, Audulomi, Kashakrtsna, Karsnajini and Atreya, as quoted by Badarayana himself.

Jainism poses that Marici was one of the previous births of Vardhamana Mahavira.

Is it by any chance that these two characters are in fact one?

Because there are many overlapping theories, which may or may not be true. They also say that Guru Nanak is a later incarnation of King Janaka.

Comment: Why do you think so? Most possibly not. Stories in Hinduism not at all match with the ones with Jainism. It looks more like Jainism question to me than Hinduism. Hinduism religion doesn't acknowledge Vardhamana Mahavira. Jainism and Hinduism stories share similarity but they are different.

Comment: founder of Vedanta? The Vedanta came from the Lord Himself. What about the Vedas, the Upanishads...the Brahma Sutras are a summary of the Upanishads. Its not the first systematized book on the Vedanta. Suggest you read some Vedanta rather than depending on the views of Western academics views in Wikipedia....try here - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: BTW Ramakrishna Paramhamsa too used to believe that Guru Nanak was an incarnation of Janaka.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I have read Vedanta Sutras by Ramanuja and Shankara and I most definitely do not depend on Wikipedia. But there seems to be some discrepancy in issues I cannot really avoid for the sake of my mental peace. So decided to drop in a query.

Comment: I also mentioned "Is it by any chance", and this proves beyond a doubt that I am not actually equating them, but asking if they might be one. I also mentioned the term "overlapping theories". Do these phrases really sound as if I am drawing parallels without prior investigation?